# Access build parameters in a custom jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a requirement to access build parameters in my custom Jenkins plugin.

I searched everywhere. But I couldn't find an answer.

How can I access build parameters in my custom Jenkins plugin code?

Comment: Please explain/post some code on whats your custom plugin doing.. It maybe helpful for answering

Comment: I found a method. This was helped for my problem. 
            EnvVars envVars;
            envVars = build.getEnvironment(listener);
            apiName = envVars.get("apiName");
            version = envVars.get("version");
            listener.getLogger().println("API_NAME : " + apiName);
            listener.getLogger().println("API_VERSION : " + version);
        Thank you very much for your cooperation @AnandVarkeyPhilips